# PHP: Submit form data with anchor tag

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am struggling to submit data to database with below code. I just wonder to know how can I submit/update table with anchor link.

How can I get id or name which is generate dynamically like `$p_id` etc.. and when submiting form it get the value properly.

Do I need to use jquery or PHP only can handle this process?

Here is my code

```
echo '<ul class="rm-media-list">'; 

                            while ($media = mysql_fetch_array($media_item)) {

                                $m_uid = $media['user_id'];
                                $m_uname = $media['user_login'];

                                $media_class = new q2a_review_media;
                                $thumb_path = $media_class->rm_thumbnail_url($pid,$m_uid);
                                $media_url = $media_class->rm_media_url($pid,$m_uid);
                                $mediaid = $media['id'];
                                $image_name = $media['image_name'];                                

                                echo '<li>';
                                echo '<span class="rm-media-user"><a href="'.admin_url( 'user-edit.php?user_id=' . $m_uid, 'http' ).'">',$m_uname,'</a></span>';
                                echo '<a href="'.$media_url.$image_name.'" rel="lightbox['.$pid.']" title="Post: '.$pid.' |  '.$ptitle.' | Image: '.$image_name.' | by: '.$m_uname.' " ><img src="'.$thumb_path.$image_name.'" alt="'.$media['image_name'].'" width="56" class="rm-thumbs-list" /></a>';
                                echo '<span class="rm-action-links"><a href="#" class="approve-button" id="'.$mediaid.'" >Approve</a> | <a href="#" class="delete-button" id="'.$mediaid.'" >Delete</a></span>';                            
                                echo '</li>';
                            }

                        echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use JavaScript and bind a click handler to the anchor. Something like this with jQuery...

**HTML**:

```
<form name="myform" id="myForm" action="foo">
    <input type="hidden" name="bar" id="bar" value="" />
</form>

<a href="#" data-val="123" class="formAnchor">Submit 123</a>
<a href="#" data-val="abc" class="formAnchor">Submit abc</a>
```

**JS**:

```
$('.formAnchor').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents a window.location change to the href
    $('#bar').val( $(this).data('val') );  // sets to 123 or abc, respectively
    $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/jtKyv/

Comment: Thanks for quick response but than how can I assume which link has been submited within the loop? there could be 5, 10 or more item with dynamic id or name so how to determine that name which I can use to get table row?

Comment: Just use a class instead then. Replace `#myAnchor` with `.myAnchor`

Comment: I think either I didn't describe my question properly. What I mean using this code than how can I determine like x click is will goes xr row? Like in normal form we determine with `name` attribute

Comment: Add a hidden field in the form and populate it on click before submit.

Comment: Hi I understand your answer but one thing I am still confuse how can I pass the id/value from javascript to my sql query and php file to insert/update into database?

Comment: Well, it would show up in PHP as `$_POST['bar']` since the JS is assigning the value to the hidden input field.

Comment: Oh I see, but than another issue. Consider there are 50 anchor links and data/id generating dynamically than how `$_POST[$id]` would determine dynamically?

Comment: It wouldn't - there's a single hidden input field with the name `bar` and the id `bar`. On clicking any of those anchors, their `data-val` gets assigned as the value for that one input field and then submits the form. PHP doesn't need to do anything special.

Comment: I am sorry if I am bothering you too much. but than where I can write my sql query to update the table? and how it will communicate with Jquery? This is first time I am using jQury in form submission so no ieda

Comment: jQuery is on the client. There's nothing special about how the form is submitted. It's just as if someone clicked a submit button. PHP doesn't talk to jQuery at all. You'd write the SQL query in your PHP file - I put `action="foo"`. That could be `action="foo.php"` and in `foo.php` you'd have `if ($_POST['bar']) { /* update mysql */ }`